# Making multiple random divs fade in and out with different timing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom

I have a problem making a server side generated code(`<php ?>`) div fade in and out.

I query a database and return six rows that I place in a div. 
Normally the div will be duplicated six times because of the while clause in the mysql query. 
The problem here is that i want the six divs to fade in and fadeout at different timing.
It does not matter which one fades in first, as long as the six dynamically generated divs fade in randomly at different times.

I know this will be jquery or javascript to which I am a newcomer.

Comment: this is going to require CSS3 and javascript. Look into css3's alpha property (rgba).

Comment: please explain more on that...@Crackers

Comment: @Crackers he should be able to accomplish what he's describing with a simple jquery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.  I not saying CSS3 is a bad thing BY ANY MEANS.  Just saying that jquery should be able to accomplish this by itself.

Comment: http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba @Jared, there are many ways to solve a problem, we have just demonstrated this.

Comment: Why does this HAVE to requires CSS3 AND JS? Why not make a one solution on either platforms? I agree with Jared, most likely fade's with callbacks are the good way to go.

Comment: I didn't say HAVE, sorry if my comment was misleading. There is a reason I choose to put it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Ok, I got some questions: There are alot of terms, that make this question much more confusing, then it really is. First, what is this script about? Why the term "duplicate", are the divs with the same style, then still why duplicate? Do you want them to display in certain timeouts, or you simply don't want them to show at the same time? I think if you would clarify your question a bit further, we could give you a much much more optimized data.

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas I only mentioned this solution because he mentionted jQuery in his original question.  CSS3 is a PERFECTLY viable option and VyrenMedia may find functionality in CSS3 that they would like to use elsewhere and hadn't thought of before.  I don't see anything wrong with Crakers suggestion (personally)! Thanks for the support of my answer though :)

Comment: @VyrenMedia if an answer below fits your needs be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
function fadeRandom($divI) { // make a function we can re-use
    window.setTimeout(function() { // do this next stuff after a short break
        $divI.fadeIn(100, function(){ // fade $divI in, then ...
            $divI.fadeOut(100, function() { // fade $divI out, then ...
                fadeRandom($divI); // start the whole cycle over
            }
        }, Math.random(100) * 100); // do that after 1-100ms
    });
}
for (var i = 0; i++; i < 6) { // go through all 6 divs and ...
    fadeRandom($('#div_' + i)); // get the fade cycle started
}
```

should work.  That's untested code, and you'll likely want to tweak the numbers, but hopefully it gives you a basic idea.

Comment: just fyi check your curly brackets you have an un-even number of opening/closing brackets

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to use a few different pieces of Javascript to accomplish what it sounds like you are wanting...

If you have six elements then you can use the `.random()` function to get the next element to swap...  Example of this is [HERE.](http://css-tricks.com/generate-a-random-number/)

jQuery has some built in methods to fade an element in/out...

[HERE for `.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

[HERE for `.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

For the timer you can use `.doTimeout()` which is demonstrated [HERE.](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/)  This is a jQuery plugin.  Javascript does have a built in timer `setInterval()`, but using `.doTimeout()` will allow you to keep the same javascript look/feel which I tend to like.